# Setting up iptables filter to allow Git

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm trying to setup my Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS server to have a solid iptables firewall. Right now I think it is pretty good, however, I cannot do any git pulls on the server when iptables is active... so the workaround is to turn off the firewall, do a pull, then re-activate the firewall. It's annoying, and introduces human error of not turning the firewall back on.

I made my iptables from a couple resources, and the git rules from here:
http://www.nigeldunn.com/2011/06/29/iptables-rules-to-allow-git/

I tried putting logging in to see what packets are getting blocked by the git pull, but nothing shows up in /var/log/kern.log (although other things get logged in there unrelated so I know it's working).

When doing a git pull I get this:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname equity1.projectlocker.com: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Here is my iptables configuration:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Flushing iptable rules"
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X

echo "Setting default drop rules"
# Setting default filter policy
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

echo "Enabling loopback"
# Allow unlimited traffic on loopback
#iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

echo "Allowing new and established incoming connections to port 22,80,443,3000, and 9418"
# Multiport - Allow incoming + outgoing 
#       SSH (22),
#       Web Traffic (80, 3000),
#       Secure Web Traffic (443)
#       Git (9418)
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443,3000,9418 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443,3000,9418 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

echo "Port forwarding from port 3000 to 80"
# Port Forward to 3000
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000

echo "Enabling ICMP (Pings, echos)"
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

echo "Preventing DDOS attacks"
# Prevent DOS Attacks
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT

echo "Enabling logging"
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: " --log-level 7
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP

# lastly:
# make sure nothing comes or goes out of this box
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

**Updated:**

```
echo "Flushing iptable rules"
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X

echo "Setting default drop rules"
# Setting default filter policy
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow DNS Queries for Git
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED     -j ACCEPT
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to allow outgoing DNS queries, thus ssh can't find the IP address for the hostname.

You need to allow outgoing traffic to TCP port 53 and UDP port 53.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I added the rule to iptables, and it got me one step farther (doesn't fail). However, it just infinitely hangs... 

I'll update my question with what I added

Comment: Looks like it times out eventually with this:

`ssh: connect to host equity1.projectlocker.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: Well, you aren't allowing that traffic either!

Comment: I thought this line allows port 22?
`iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443,3000,9418 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443,3000,9418 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Comment: You only allowed inbound connections, not outbound ones.

Comment: Sorry, I'm under the impression that the "OUTPUT -o" is the outbound connection? Am I missing the outbound port 22 for UDP? Or do I need to add a destination id with the -d?

Comment: Any more help with this? Sorry I'm confused :(

Answer (score 2):

In addition to allowing DNS queries, you will need to allow traffic via port 9418.

> Git uses port 9418 to communicate. You don’t want to open up the port
>   externally so I used stateful inspection to open the port only if we
>   established the connection.

```
 # allow git
    sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 9418 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 9418 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

In my case, I used a slight variation (I used conntrack instead of state).

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 9418 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 9418 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

REFERENCE: http://www.nigeldunn.com/2011/06/29/iptables-rules-to-allow-git/

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry, I'm under the impression that the "OUTPUT -o" is the outbound connection? Am I missing the outbound port 22 for UDP? Or do I need to add a destination id with the -d?

I'm using CentOS 7 so my syntax for iptables will be a bit differently than yours; but it will give the same general idea of what you need to write.

If I wanted to open up the TCP port 22 I would write the following:

```
# Open TCP port 22 for incoming traffic:
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Open TCP port 22 for outgoing traffic:
-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

You will notice the syntax uses INPUT paired with --dport 22 and OUTPUT paired with --sport 22 for the incoming. It is the opposite for the outgoing; INPUT with --sport 22 and OUTPUT with --dport 22. Hope this helps someone!